# Facebook mobile: link to external app?

Tags: facebook

Imagine you want to create a contest app for Facebook using the SaaS approach.
So, you create the app and let business pages FB users to install it in a custom tab. Using the facebook context information (user_id, page_id, etc) it is easy to index the account in the database to the FB instalation).

Now imagine that you want to put the same app available to the Facebook mobile app. As far as i know, FB mobile app does not suport custom tabs right? So the contest app could not be 'hosted' in a custom tab...

Does Facebook mobile App has any place where the contest app could be 'hosted/linked' in order that mobile users of that business page could see it and use it?

If so, how to register/install/link the contest app to that business page in mobile FB?

Thanks a lot
Alex

Comment: Correct, page tabs are not available on mobile. So you can only show the app outside of Facebook, stand-alone. No “installation” on any Facebook page possible in that case.

Comment: Right, but is there any way or place/section in facebook mobile  where a link to that exyernal aplication can be created (in order to be associated with that mobile facebook application)?

Comment: When you configure the “Website” platform for your app, you can specify a Mobile Site URL. But you can not “associate” a page with it – apart from perhaps putting it somewhere into the page’s about section, or posting the link on the page’s timeline.

Comment: yes, i know that it is posible to write the mobile site url in the app configuration. My problem is having the link always present in the user view field. Puting it in the timeline will desapear/go down with the time, putting it in the about page seems good but can about page have a new field/custom field? Or should we use existing fields to publish the link?

Comment: No, you can not put new fields in there.